# Looking for the name of this property, if it has one.

Tags: bounded-variation, monotone-functions

I'm looking for the name of this property or a book where I can find it: If a function is upper bounded and non-decresing, the infinity limit exists.. I'm sure I saw this somewhere, could you help me?

Comment: I don't think it has a name, it is just a fact - that bounded monotonic sequences converge. It is called the Monotone convergence theorem on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem)

Comment: The *monotone convergence theorem*.